# Telnet router via batch, get info and export to csv file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I set up a small 3 router network via GNS3. I can connect on it via my pc (telnet) and execute simple cisco commands like show int brief.
Now I found a batch file here that I modified a little to login all 3 routers and execute the show ip int brief command. I have all the info on my screen, but I would like to have it in a .csv file.

I changed the router IP's
R1: 1.1.1.1, R2: 2.2.2.2, R3: 3.3.3.3

This is the batch-file

```
:: Open a Telnet window
start telnet.exe 1.1.1.1             
:: Run the script
cscript showipintbrief.vbs
```

This is the vbs file (showipintbrief.vbs):

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "loginR1password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enable{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enableR1password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "show ip int brief{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
Echo Interface, IP-Address > showipintbrief.csv
OBJECT.SendKeys "telnet 2.2.2.2{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "loginR2password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enable{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enableR2password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "show ip int brief{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "telnet 3.3.3.3{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "loginR3password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enable{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "enableR3password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "show ip int brief{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
```

For instance Interface, Ip-address, status and protocol should be sent to a .csv file

Anyone can help wiht this please?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this to log the data and execute it from the cmd prompt, where batchfile.bat is your batch file name.

```
batchfile.bat >file.log
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried this already but the output in my file looks like this:

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.

This si not what I have on my cmd window...

Comment: Hi again foxidrive. Thanks for your answer, but it is still NOK. Must be something stupid but I do not see it. I added your configuration line in the .bat and after that also in the .vbs file but it is not what I need. 
If you would know how to do this in perl that would be good too.

Comment: Remove any changes to the VBS command and batch file and then execute the command in my answer from the cmd prompt. What do you see in the log file after running it?

Comment: 1. when launching the .bat file, it executes the .vbs and at the end the cmd window closes. 
2. when I put the commands manually (telnet to router, login router and show ip int brief) at the R3# prompt, i type exit and then my cmd window does not close. When I add your command in there this is the message I get : "
C:\Documents and Settings\user1\GNS3\Projects\Fixed Service Delivery Netwerk Basics>testshowipintbrief.bat > file20.log
'testshowipintbrief.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Read my last comment carefully, and the answer.  You don't put anything inside the batch file.

Comment: Hi Hoxidrive, I managed to get the file via a batch from where I launch putty. In putty I modified the default settings with logging on. Thanks for your help.